# Consistency of systems of inequalities involving only differences

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms

I have a very large number (670 billion) of systems of inequalities of the form:

$C_1 - C_2 < C_4 - C_3 \wedge C_3 - C_2 < C_5 - C_3 \wedge ...$

where the $C_i > 0$. Ie. each system of inequalities consists of the comparisons of differences between positive real numbers which must all be true at the same time.

Now I want to find the subset of systems which are consistent, ie. there exists a choice of $C_i$ such that all inequalities are satisfied.

Given the the large number of systems this method would have to be automated. Therefore my question is:

Is there an algorithm to decide whether a system of inequalities of the form described above is consistent?

Comment: That's a lot of systems -- if each takes a second to determine consistency than you will need 21 thousand years of machine time.

Comment: how many variables are there?

Comment: @JJ yes it's a lot of systems. But they are not actually unique as many of them are related by symmetry, but I have not worked out the actual symmetry. Furthermore for my problem I only need one example of a consistent system.

Comment: @Brendan, there are 8 variables in total

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it.  If there are only 8 variables, only a small number (less than $4^8=65536$) of different inequalities of the form $C_i-C_j<C_k-C_\ell$ can exist. So how can you have 670 billion?

Comment: The system I am studying can be in one of 30 states, the state graph is such that there are 20 cycles (of length 6). Each state transition is associated with a $\Theta$, an $i$-$j$ pair and whether $C_i - C_j$ is larger or smaller than $\Theta$.
I am looking for an assignment of 10 inputs (consisting of 5 $C_i$ each) to 10 cycles. By my calculation that means I have $\binom{20}{10}*10!$ possible assignments.
For each possible assignment I can then construct a system of inequalities as described in the question.

Comment: @Brendan: You have $4^8$ of these inequalities. But now you consider systems of them. Now there are $\binom{4^8}{k}$ systems consisting $k$ inequalities. In total, there are $2^{4^8}$ such systems (including the empty one, and a majority which are readily seen to be inconsistent), but still, there are certainly a lot left where it is not immediately clear whether they are consistent or not.

Comment: Oh I see, 670 billion is the number of problems that have to be solved.  I read it as the number of inequalities in one problem, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hellooooooooo !!!

This could be done by a linear solver... to some extent ! A linear program accepts a set of constraints of the form (linear function >= 0), and tells you whether there exists an assignment of values to your variables such that all the constraints are satisfied.

The "only difference" between your problem and what a LP solver can do is that the LP solver cannot understand strict inequalities. Hence you would have to add linear constraints of the form variable >= some_very_small_value.

I think these answers could still be useful to you. Theoretically, you can even obtain certificated of infeasibility (a set of ocnflicting constraints), but it is harder to obtain in practice.

If you want to give it a try, you should look for Linear Program solvers like GLPK (free), CPLEX(proprietary), Coin (free), Gurobi (Proprietary). These programs accept as input a .mps or .lp file describing your set of constraints (I expect this to appear in the documentation of each of these solvers).

You can als do this computation through Sage (http://www.sagemath.org), and by looking at this short tutorial on LP (for graph applications !)
http://steinertriples.fr/ncohen/tut/LP/

Good luck ! ;-)

Nathann

Comment: sorry I forgot to add something : if you want to find out about these certificates, the keyword is "farkas certificate"

Comment: Since in this case, all inequalities are strict (or at least this seems to be the case, according what derfred wrote so far), one can actually solve this exactly by asking whether the polytope defined by the non-strict inequalities $c_i-c_j\leq c_k-c_\ell$ has empty interior or not (i.e. is full-dimensional). This is certainly doable, but it might be expensive if there are many inequalities in your systems... In fact, how large are your systems "on average"?

Comment: Given any real solution $\{C_i\}$ of the strict inequalities, multiply by a large enough constant so that difference between the sides of each inequality exceeds 2, then round each variable to the nearest integer.

Therefore it suffices to consider integer solutions of the non-strict inequalities $C_i-C_j\le C_k-C_\ell-1$.